# PHP PDO Transactions?

Tags: php, pdo, transactions

I have a signup page and basically I need data inserted into 4 tables. I'm new to PDO and am confused over something.

Basically if any of the inserts fail I don't want anything added to the database, that seems simple enough.

My confusion is, I need to first insert the users username, email, password etc in my `users` table so I can get (not sure how) using PDO the uid MySQL has given my user (auto incremented by mysql). I need the user uid MySQL gave my user for the other tables as the other tables needs the uid so everything is linked properly together. My tables are InnoDB and I have foreign keys going from users_profiles(user_uid), users_status(user_uid), users_roles(user_uid) to the users.user_uid so they are all linked together.

But at the same time I want to ensure that if for example after data is inserted in the `users` table (so I can get the uid MySQL gave user) that if any of the other inserts fail that it removes the data that was inserted into the `users` table.

I thinks it's best I show my code; I have commented out the code and have explained in the code which may make it easier to understand.

```
// Begin our transaction, we need to insert data into 4 tables:
// users, users_status, users_roles, users_profiles
// connect to database
$dbh = sql_con();

// begin transaction
$dbh->beginTransaction();

try {

    // this query inserts data into the `users` table
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('
                        INSERT INTO `users`
                        (users_status, user_login, user_pass, user_email, user_registered)
                        VALUES
                        (?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())');

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $userstatus,     PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $username,       PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $HashedPassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(4, $email,          PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    // get user_uid from insert for use in other tables below
    $lastInsertID = $dbh->lastInsertId();

    // this query inserts data into the `users_status` table
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('
                        INSERT INTO `users_status`
                        (user_uid, user_activation_key)
                        VALUES
                        (?, ?)');

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $lastInsertID,     PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $activationkey,    PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    // this query inserts data into the `users_roles` table
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('
                        INSERT INTO `users_roles`
                        (user_uid, user_role)
                        VALUES
                        (?, ?)');

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $lastInsertID,      PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, SUBSCRIBER_ROLE,    PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    // this query inserts data into the `users_profiles` table
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare('
                        INSERT INTO `users_profiles`
                        (user_uid)
                        VALUES
                        (?)');

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $lastInsertID,      PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    // commit transaction
    $dbh->commit();

} // any errors from the above database queries will be catched
catch (PDOException $e) {
    // roll back transaction
    $dbh->rollback();
    // log any errors to file
    ExceptionErrorHandler($e);
    require_once($footer_inc);
    exit;
}
```

I'm new to PDO and there maybe errors or problems above I have yet to notice because I can't test yet until I figure out my problem.

1. I need to know how I can insert the users data in the users table first so i can get the uid MySQL gave my user
2. Then get the uid as I need it for the other tables
3. But at the same time if a query fails for whatever reason after inserting into users table that the data is also deleted from the users table aswell.

Comment: a) Put the `$dbh->beginTransaction();` and the line before that outside of the try/catch block - you can't rollback anything until the transaction is started. b) What is not working with this? Just use lastInsertId as usual.

Comment: @Niko, i will do this in a moment, thank you phplover

Comment: @Niko, i edited code above to reflect the change you said, can i ask why can't the `$dbh->beginTransaction();` be in the try block also ? don't quite understand that bit, thanks phplover

Comment: Just retrieving the ID and don't using it doesn't make any sense, right? Should be something like this: `$userId = $dbh->lastInsertId();` - I don't think that a call to beginTransaction() from within the try/catch block really causes problems most the time, but if beginning the transaction fails and a PDO exception is raised, you would try to rollback a transaction before one got started. That leeds to undefined behavior, most likely a new error. Apart from that you got everything very right.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This function returns primary key of just inserted record: [PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)
You will need it for `NEED_USERS_UID_FOR_HERE` parameter.  Use it just after INSERT statement.

Since you started a transaction, data will not be inserted into any table if any error occures provided you use InnoDB engine for your MySQL tables (MyISAM doesn't support transactions).

Comment: thanks i think i'm understanding it now, i put `$dbh->lastInsertId();` after the INSERT statement (see edited code in original post), now i got the last insert id doing what you said above, how do i now access the last insert id to put it in the other queries `NEED_USERS_UID_FOR_HERE` ? sorry im new to PDO so still figuring it out, thanks phplover

Comment: sorry think i could explain that bit better, do i simply assign a variable to `$dbh->lastInsertId();` so it becomes something like `$lastInsertID = $dbh->lastInsertId();` and then Where it says `NEED_USERS_UID_FOR_HERE` just replace that with `$lastInsertID` ? thanks phplover

Comment: Yes. Just store it as a variable and use it in further queries. It won't be written to the database if the transaction fails.

Comment: Both FractalizeR and Niko provided good answers that has helped me and is difficult to choose an accepted answer but because FractalizeR was first to reply and will choose yours as the accepted answer. Thank you to both of you for all your help, phplover, will test it all in a few minutes.