# try catch, and multiple mysql insert statement. Will it accept all or deny all queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, transactions, try-catch

Hey I have question to you guys. If I implement my sql mysql insert in try catch will that prevent from executing only partial INSERT into database if one of them will fail ?

```
try
{
//SQL INSET TABLE 1
//SQL INSET TABLE 2
//SQL INSET TABLE 3
//SQL INSET TABLE 4
}
catch(Exception $e)
{...}
```

I would like to deny all or accept all. Is that they way to do that?

Regarding to your comment. I am using PDO. I would be grateful for the configuration example that would allow that.

In Your comments you often recommending transaction and rollback. Can anyone give an example  with some comments on the code? x

I would also like to know if there is some alternative ways of achieving this effect.

@SOLUTION FOUND AT: [PHP + MySQL transactions examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708237/php-mysql-transactions-examples):

```
try {
    // First of all, let's begin a transaction
    $db->beginTransaction();

    // A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
    $db->query('first query');
    $db->query('second query');
    $db->query('third query');

    // If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
    // i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
    $db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // An exception has been thrown
    // We must rollback the transaction
    $db->rollback();
}
```

Note that, with this idea, if a query fails, an Exception must be thrown:

PDO can do that, depending on how you configure it
See PDO::setAttribute
and PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE and PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
else, with some other API, you might have to test the result of the function used to execute a query, and throw an exception yourself.

Unfortunately, there is no magic involved. You cannot just put an instruction somewhere and have transactions done automatically: you still have to specific which group of queries must be executed in a transaction.

For example, quite often you'll have a couple of queries before the transaction (before the begin) and another couple of queries after the transaction (after either commit or rollback) and you'll want those queries executed no matter what happened (or not) in the transaction.

ANOTHER HELPFUL LINK: [PHP PDO Transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155946/php-pdo-transactions)

Comment: Using what MySQL API?  Most of them _do not support exceptions_ and will not throw them at all.  PDO will if configured.

Comment: If you want to rollback all queries on a failure, look into using transactions.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: To be more succint, if an insert/update query is executed successfully and is not part of a transaction. It will be in the database before the next query is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. `try/catch` will NOT "undo" failed queries if one of those fails. You need a transaction:

```
try {
   start transaction;
   insert 1;
   insert 2;
   ...
   commit;
} catch {
   rollback;
}
```

Comment: You also need to ensure that an exception is thrown if a statement fails.

Comment: Which you can do manually if required, like `throw new Exception("OH NOES!")`

Comment: Could you present an example in PDO ? or MySQL? ;*

Answer (score 1):

you should use transactions and rollback in the catch block.