# Create an sql sentence that has tree query? SQL

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to create a query that executes three sentence, but i think its not possible, the top its two, the issue is that i have two tables, one its called current_products and the other one its called finished_products, once a product is finished the data that is in the current_product table is passed to the finished_products table, that would be:

```
$query = self::connect()->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
                    (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) 
                SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
                FROM `current_products` 
                WHERE `room`=:room
            );
$query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
```

once its passed, i want to delete the data of the current_product table where the room is the same room that i pass, something like this:

```
$query = self::connect()->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
                    (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) 
                SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
                FROM `current_products` 
                WHERE `room`=:room; 
            DELETE * FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room;"
        );
$query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
```

but like i said, it neither works nor possible, i was thinking to create a trigger that executes in the finished_products table once its execute the sentence INSERT in it, something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DELETECURRENTPRODUCT_AI AFTER INSERT ON `finished_products` DELETE * FROM `current_products` WHERE room = new.room
```

but its always telling me that theres an error close to DELETE, so i dont know well how the syntax is, i tried a lot of ways but it seems doesnt work, other people told me to use transactions, but seeing it, its like execute two querys one after another one, like this:

```
$query = self::connect()->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO `finished_products` 
                (room, name, lot, quantity_packed, pallet) 
                SELECT room, name, lot, quantity_to_package, finished_pallets 
                FROM `current_products` 
                WHERE `room`=:room);

$query->execute(["room"=>$room]);

$query = self::connect()->prepare("DELETE * FROM `current_products` WHERE `room`=:room);
$query->execute(["room"=>$room]);
```

the difference its it will rollback if theres an error, but for what i trying to do i dont think i need to use transactions, is there a way to do it? thanks :)

Comment: You have a syntax error; a missing quote to close the query with. Or, what that a bad paste or intentional?

Comment: You cannot run 2 queries using the `query()` method.

Comment: its a bad paste xD

Comment: Use the 2 consecutive queries (insert, delete) and do them inside a Transaction

Comment: `DELETE *` < that isn't the way it's one; get rid of the asterisk.

Comment: @RiggsFolly how would that be?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, CREATE TRIGGER DELETECURRENTPRODUCT_AI AFTER INSERT ON `finished_products` DELETE FROM `current_products` WHERE room = new.room, it stills telling me error

Comment: See [this Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155946/php-pdo-transactions) for a good example